# React JS creating interface for an array being passed to map function array.map(item:???)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i was told to make an interface for my code for .map, but i am not sure how do i do this, I been looking for a while but can not find any examples i isolated code with ###. Any help would be appreciated.

I have update interface part but still getting issues

```
interface ItemCategories{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  categoryImg: string;
}

import React, { FC, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CategoryButton from "./CategoryButton";
import axios from "axios";
import "../assets/stylesheets/CategoryList.css";

const CategoryList: FC = () => {
  const [itemCategories, setItemCategories]: ItemCategories[] = useState([]);
  const categorySelection = (categoryType: string) => {
    console.log(categoryType);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateData = async () => {
      const results = await axios.request({
        method: "get",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/categories",
      });
      setItemCategories(results.data);
    };
    updateData();
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="cs-hs-scroll-div">
      <div className="cs-category-selection  w-100">
        {itemCategories.length > 0 ? (
          itemCategories.map((itemCategory: ItemCategories) => (

              <CategoryButton
                key={itemCategory.id.toString()}
                textData={itemCategory.name}
                id={itemCategory.id}
                categoryImgUrl={itemCategory.categoryImg}
                onBtnClick={categorySelection}
              />

          ))
        ) : (
          <div />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategoryList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this below;

```
interface ItemCategory {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    categoryImg: string;
}
```

This next line in your code;

```js
const [itemCategories, setItemCategories]: any[] = useState([]);
```

You need to change the type array of any, to an array of ItemCategory. Like this;

```js
const [itemCategories, setItemCategories]: ItemCategory[] = useState([]);
```

The type of a single item in the map can be changed to;

```js
itemCategory: ItemCategory
```

Comment: I tried that but does not fix my issue, i updated the code

Comment: I described "something" like this, not literally copypaste the Interface. You issue was how to create and implement an Interface right?

Comment: itemCategory: ItemCategories should be itemCategory: ItemCategory. + you can't create an interface for map, but you can for itemCategories.

Comment: My issue was how to create an interface for ```itemCategories.map```
I want to be able to itemCategory.id  = id  , and itemCategory.name = name, and etc

Comment: Thank you, i misunderstood request, I never worked with typescript before, I was not sure what they wanted but your confirming it is not possible helped